# Find duplicate using regex in a txt file opened with Sublime Text 3 editor

Tags: regex, duplicates, sublimetext3

I have the following table, written in a txt file.

```
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| Reference Date | Instrument ID | Entity ID  |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4251675720    | 1000183742 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4251675720    | 1000183742 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 2113750655    | 100065856  |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 3512075270    | 1002923999 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4251998103    | 1003890261 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4239113350    | 1004043945 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 8569030255    | 1004043945 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 6692802619    | 1004584989 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 6751615521    | 1005048991 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 1338818134    | 1005076529 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 1903780287    | 1005519781 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 3023132803    | 1005535434 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 3075990149    | 1006443568 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 1821112520    | 1007165898 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4249904989    | 100753094  |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 4230960972    | 1009300504 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28     | 2254190165    | 1010611747 |
+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

The file looks like this:

[image]

The txt file is opened from Sublime Text 3 (file Editor).

**My problem**: I don't want to have duplicates and I thought since Sublime Text supports the Find/Replace functionality with regex to find those duplicates and remove them by hand.
Specifically, I want to find the duplicates in columns Instrument ID, Entity ID. For example, if you check the first two rows both have the same pair (Instrument ID, Entity ID). Using regex I want to find the rest of the rows with the same pair and by hand remove the second row.

Keep in mind that in my txt file the syntax is: `1000183742         1006443568` (6 spaces+1 tab between the columns). So with regex I am looking for the same pair with

- `d{10}\s{6}\t{1}\d{10}` -> 10 digits, followed by 6 spaces, followed by 1 tab, followed by 10 digits

Comment: Try it like this `\b(\d{10}) {6}\t(\d{10})\b(?=[\s\S]*\b\1 {6}\t\2)\b` https://regex101.com/r/6AzjpX/1

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post with a cut-and-paste from your file (without the table formatting) for testing?

Comment: So, if I understand you, you want to get the Instrument ID/Entity ID pair from each line and search the rest of the file for matching lines, then go on to the next line and do the same. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the digits in 2 capturing groups and assert that they occur at the right.

```
\b(\d{10}) {6}\t(\d{10})\b(?=[\s\S]*\b\1 {6}\t\2)\b
```

- `\b(\d{10})` Word boundary, capture 10 digits in group 1
- `{6}\t` Match 6 spaces and a tab
- `(\d{10})\b` Capture 10 digits in group 2 and word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that what is at the right contains

  - `[\s\S]*` Match any char 0+ times
- `\b\1 {6}\t\2)\b` Match the exact matched values in group 1 and 2 using a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AzjpX/1/)

You could also switch it around and get the matches that do not have duplicate value at the right using a negative lookahead instead. Note that I have used `\d{9,10}` as not all values are 10 digits

```
\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ \t]+\b(\d{9,10}) {6}\t(\d{9,10})\b(?![\s\S]*\b\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wUoLv/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Excuse me for the late response...Your first snippet of code find every match. However, the second does not find any match whatsoever. The first snippet matches every pair which is correct but I want only the duplicates. Can you define with regex the duplicates?

Comment: @NikSp I think it should be like this without the date part https://regex101.com/r/VXKTem/1 `\b(\d{9,10}) {6}\t(\d{9,10})\b(?![\s\S]*\b\1 {6}\t\2)\b`

Comment: For a reason this command freezes my Sublime Text editor

Comment: I think that is due to the number of steps, is it a large file?

Comment: Yeah 135,000 rows...7,6Mb not that large but my editor freezes when I post your command on find/replace line.

Comment: For that many rows, I think regex is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Hhmmm ok, maybe also sublime is not the right editor....Probably Python would do the job. In any case thank you for your suggestions. Are you sure that your code will find the duplicate rows?

Comment: You could try that instead yes, then I think you have to load the whole file at once instead of line by line.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Have a great rest of your day